# React JS routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

one of my devs recently updated a route component from common approach

```
<Route path="/loggingin" component={LoggingIn}/>
<Route path="/forgottenpassword" component={ForgottenPassword}/>
<Route path="/passwordreset" component={PasswordReset}/>
<Route path="/changepassword" component={ChangePassword}/>
...more routes here
```

to

```
export const mainRoutes: TypeRoutes = {

    ...loginRoutes,
    ...formRoutes,

    // NON LOGGED IN ROUTES
    '/': {
        pageComponent: PageHome,
        exact: true
    },

    // MAIN ROUTES
    '/manufacturer-products': {
        pageComponent: ManufacturersProducts,
        exact: true
    },
    '/accounts': {
        pageComponent: Accounts,
        exact: true
    },
    '/help': {
        pageComponent: HelpPage,
        exact: true
    },

    '/details/:message?': {
        pageComponent: PageDetails,
        exact: true
    } };

 function renderRoutes(routes: TypeRoutes): Array<TypeComponent> {

     return Object.keys(routes).map((key: string): TypeComponent =>
         (<Route key={key}
             path={key}
            exact={routes[key].exact}
             component={getAuthorizedComponent(routes[key])} />)); 
}
```

So basically every time navigation will loop over an array of routes. I haven't tested performance but my concern is that this approach will clutter the application because of often re-rendering.

Will it have an implication on performance? Any suggestions or relevant articles are much appreciated.

Comment: why do you think it re-renders more often?

Comment: Actually I don't know if it does. I wonder if this is a good approach to render elements in the dom. Would you use this style? Which one would you prefer.

Comment: Is this V4? If so doesn't each non-page render null anyway? So iteration or not it's still rendering the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Put a `console.log('hi')` in the `renderRoutes` function to see if it ever prints more than once.

Most router setups will be static, and at the top of the virtual dom tree, and thus only render once.